# Cannot find type definition file for 'core-js'

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular2 project and using  [angular2-tree component](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/) for handling tree structure. After installing tree component and when I do npm start, I am getting below error:

- Cannot find type definition file for 'core-js'

I googled this error and find the work-around for this of removing commented line from one of its TS file. I am trying to find the root cause of this error and the proper solution of this.

Below are the version details of my project:

1. angular2-tree-component: ^2.6.1
2. core-js: ^2.4.1

Below is the file name and the commented line which I deleted as a work-around.

File Name: `tree-node.model.d.ts`

Code : `/// <reference types="core-js" />`

Any lead on this will be helpful and let me know for any missing details.

Answer (score 3):

From typescript v2.0 , typings need not be mentioned as reference tag.

Instead you can install typings as:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/core-js
```

tsc automatically looks for typings in @types folder in node_modules

This should solve the problem